# Why doesn't Mortal Kombat X open on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: linux, mortal-kombat-x

I'm trying to run Mortal Kombat X on Ubuntu 15.04, but WINE doesn't want to open it.

It brings up this error. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot of issue described above - text below]

"There is no Windows program configured to open this type of file."

Comment: I think this question should go over to http://askubuntu.com

Comment: Also, you should make sure you have not pirated stuff on your desktop.Since it is fair to assume that you have pirated MKX too, I vote to close.

Comment: Are you sure this game is supported by Ubuntu?